# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I saw several answers for this question, but none of them solved my problem. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AubJaosfI-0&t=458s) tutorial to create a simple JavaFX application with a button. At first, it worked totally fine. But, when I close VS Code and open it again it shows the error:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I added vmArgs to my launch.json file:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-19/lib\" --add-modules javafx.media,javafx.base,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```

This is the Java code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btOK = new Button("OK");
    Scene scene = new Scene(btOK, 200, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("MyJavaFX");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Application.launch(args);
}
}
```

This is the launch.json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Java",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "classpath": [
            ".",
            "${fileDirname}"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Java Console App",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "startupClass": "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "classpath": [
            ".",
            "${fileDirname}"
        ],
        "externalConsole": true
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Launch Current File",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "${file}"
    },
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Launch App",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "App",
        "projectName": "bookFirst_4a14754a",
        "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/Program Files/Java/javafx-sdk-19/lib\" --add-modules javafx.media,javafx.base,javafx.graphics,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
    }
]
}
```

Here are the screenshots if required:
[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM0oG.png)

[Java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG5Ho.png)

[Settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8wfl.png)

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode

Comment: @jewelsea done, screenshots are still there yo show referenced libraries

Answer (score 0):

##### VS Code uses the currently open folder as the workspace.

As you can see from your screenshot, you have two `bookFirst` folders. For the sake of convenience, let's call your first-level `bookFirst` folder `BOOKFIRST-1` and your second-level `bookFirst` folder `bookFirst-2`.

[image]

You opened the `BOOKFIRST-1` folder as a vscode workspace, but your project is indeed inside the `bookFirst-2` folder under the `BOOKFIRST-1` folder.

##### Solution

Open the `bookFirst-2` folder as workspace in VS code.